# Passing selenium response to a callback (SCRAPY)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, captcha

I'm making a spider in Scrapy, and I realized that I had to use Selenium (maybe splash i'll try it later) for the first part which is a form with dynamic captcha, so I got to enter in the page, but now i need to pass the response to scrapy because i want to do the extraction with scrapy. I have read something about DOWNLOAD MIDDLEWARES but i don't quite get it.

So this is my code:

```
def parse(self, response):
     #do something with selenium, break captcha and enter main page
     urlRequest = driver.current_url
                if wasCaptchaBroken:
                    yield Request(url= urlRequest, callback = self.parse_each_url)

def parse_each_url(self,response):

    print("IN : " + response)

    yield{
        'url': response.url,
        'response':response
    }
```

My code never enter to parse_each_url, so i modify my settings.py:

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'my_project.middlewares.MyProjectSpiderMiddleware': 543,
    'my_project.middlewares.SeleniumMiddleware' : 600
}
```

And middleware.py:

```
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from selenium import webdriver

class SeleniumMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        driver = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        driver.get(request.url)

        body = driver.page_source
        return HtmlResponse(driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8', request=request)
```

But it's the same, what do i have to do? to pass the response of the selenium to my callback function?? do i have to call it? or something?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post crawl log? You can do this via `scrapy crawl spider --logfile output.log` or `scrapy crawl spider 2>1 | tee output.log` commands (the later puts output to screen and file).

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Where is wasCaptchaBroken defined? What does parse() look like after you moved Selenium handling to a middleware? (or did you not modify parse() at all after that?)